# Eclipse ADT Plugin - Graphical Layout tool lagging and eating memory

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

Win7 64, 12GB RAM, i7
ADT v.16.01

My graphical layout tool acting very strange. Everytime I make a single change, the tool buttons above the layout display flicker and it 'works' for about 10 seconds until it finally completes the change.. in this process, javaw.exe consumes about 800mb of RAM for every action I take on the tool.. I've gotten up to 8GB of ram being used by javaw at one point..

I've tried so many combinations of eclipse and java jre's. I've tried jre 6u21, 6u30, 7u2, all in 32/64 bit versions. Even tried eclipse indigo and developer version of Juno in both 32/64bit versions.. all do the same thing..

I had this happen before and after a new install it went away. All the sudden it started doing it again today and I have no idea why.

Anyone else come across this?

Was playing with it more and once got an error:
'programmer.xml: GC overhead limit exceeded'

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're using ADT 16.01? I saw that this was an issue in 2010, fixed by [this patch](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/15715/). Did you download ADT directly through Eclipse?

Comment: Yeah, I used the install new software in eclipse using the adt url. http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/  I've installed eclipse like 4 times this very day. In about - Eclipse it shows 16.0.1v201112150204-238534

Comment: v20.03 still same problem

Answer (score 2):

Try allocating more memory to Eclipse, if you haven't done so already. In your eclipse folder, edit *eclipse.ini* and bump the values for Xms and Xmx. I'm using:

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
```