# Eclipse ADT Plugin - Graphical Layout flickers and eats up memory

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

As there's no response to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223433/eclipse-adt-plugin-graphical-layout-tool-lagging-and-eating-memory) and I'm not sure if it has been noticed at all since it was an open question I posted to here's the thing again in hope someone can help me ;)

When I do anything in the graphical layout editor of the ADT the layout buttons (center horizontally, vertically etc) start to flicker for about 10 seconds. During this time the RAM used by Eclipse's JVM is increasing by about 200 MiB. This RAM also isn't freed at any time until I completely close Eclipse. This is especially nasty as I can only do about 6 actions per Eclipse session until I have to restart it to get the RAM freed up again.

Environment:
Windows XP SP3
JDK 1.6.0_31
Eclipse 3.7
ADT 16.0.1

Plug-Ins: [http://pastebin.com/b1ZT4904]

Any hints are welcome =)

Regards,
Chris

Comment: And I take it you've tried the patch suggested in the other question?

Comment: As the patch state is "Merged" I suspected it actually was merged -> should be in the ADT releases since july 2010. Otherwise I'd have to actually recompile the whole ADT myself which I'd like to avoid ;)

Comment: Just tried to check whether this patch is included in the upstram 16.0.1 release but unfortunately lots of stuff has changed since the patch was created so I can't find out whether it is included in the release or not.

Also I can't apply this patch to 16.0.1 as it just doesn't fit the current source anymore.

Any ideas left?

Comment: Not a clue, can you code the design for now? Rather than use the graphics editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new lint eat up memory and flickering buttons, when checking. Temporary switch off some checks. (or the "when saving ..." checkbox) You can found it in Window/Preferences menu ->search "lint".

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this problem. After searching for a solution I tried turning off the two checkboxes in Window/Preferences/Android/Lint Error Checking. This helped a little bit, but the Java Stack heap continued to grow until Eclipse either crashed or I had to close it before it did.

What ended up compounding the problem for me was some of the heights and widths were using "dip" instead of "dp" as the measurement unit and probably more importantly, "dp" in the TextSize attribute instead of "sp".

So change all units to "dp" except for testsize use "sp"