# Why does eclipse flicker and is slow to load XML in Editors?

Tags: xml, eclipse, performance, editor, flicker

My android ADT Eclipse has gotten into a state where every time I switch between XML editors it is slow.  Additionally there is a flicker of the *Reload Dependencies* and *Turn Grammar Constraints Off* toolbar buttons.  How do I fix this?

Comment: [Allocating more memory seems to have helped.][1] but it still flickers...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223433/eclipse-adt-plugin-graphical-layout-tool-lagging-and-eating-memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Eclipse 4.2 or 4.2.1, where there is a [known performance issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=394588) when switching between XML based editors. Upgrade to Eclipse 4.2.2 using the update manager.

EDIT: Meanwhile Eclipse 4.3 has been released with even more performance fixes. Everyone is advised to upgrade again.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you eclips memory is low for your operation. so you can go to eclips.ini file where eclips installed and open it. you will see like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

then increase Xmx512m to 1024 and XX:MaxPermSize=256m to XX:MaxPermSize=1024m . hope helpfull.